# URL is updating but page is not redirecting in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Here in my project I am trying to redirect to checkout page by clicking on cart icon. The url is getting updated but it's not redirecting to the new page.

- `react-router-dom@5.2.0`
- `react@18.2.0`

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import Home from './Home';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Checkout from './Checkout';
// import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="app">
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/checkout">
            <Checkout />
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Header.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './Header.css'
import SearchIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Search';
import ShoppingCartIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ShoppingCart';
import { BrowserRouter, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider';

function Header() {
  const [{ basket }, dispatch] = useStateValue();

  return (
    <div className='header'>
      <Link exact to='/'>
        <img className='header__logo' src="assets/logo.png"></img>
      </Link>
      
      <div className='header__search'>
        <input className='header__searchInput' type='text' />
        <SearchIcon className='header__searchIcon' />
      </div>
      <div className='header__nav'>
        <div className='header__option'>
          <span className='header__optionLineOne'>Hello Guest</span>
          <span className='header__optionLineTwo'>Sign In</span>
        </div>
        <div className='header__option'>
          <span className='header__optionLineOne'>Returns</span>
          <span className='header__optionLineTwo'>& Orders</span>
        </div>
        <div className='header__option'>
          <span className='header__optionLineOne'>Your</span>
          <span className='header__optionLineTwo'>Prime</span>
        </div>
             
        <Link to="/checkout">
          <div className='header__optionBasket'>
            <ShoppingCartIcon />
            <span className='header__optionLineOne header__basketCount'>
              {basket?.length}
            </span>
          </div>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header
```

Previously there is no `exact` prop, but after some browsing in stack overflow I added `exact` but still no use.

```
<Route exact path="/checkout">
  <Checkout />
</Route>
<Route exact path="/">
  <Home />
</Route>
```